# Using an array of image urls with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Basically I have an array of image urls that I am trying to pass to fancy box

```
$('#' + value.id).click(function(){
                                $.fancybox({


                                });
                        })
```

There is a div that I click and i need it to open fancybox with a gallery.

I just need to know how i would iterate through an array to get elements out and format it to pass to fancy box or if there is a way to pass an entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through an array using `for loop` or using:

```
// Create a string which will store my formated array data
var s = new String();
yourarray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
 // Format array data here. For example I will concatenate all the elements in the array with space  between them
 s.concat(element + " ");
};
// Pass s to fancybox
```

Comment: Yes but how would i pass all those as hrefs to fancy box.